# What actually happens to Jade in Part 9 of “Djinn”?

Tags: comics, djinn

In the *Djinn* graphic novels by Dufaux and Miralles, in the ninth part, "The Gorilla King", what actually becomes of the character Jade, the eponymous Djinn, after her encounter with the Gorilla King?

Does Jade become a literal legend? Is she reborn as her daughter or granddaughter Kim? Or is there another explanation?